# Bulk SQL statement for alter table add composite primary key

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, ddl

I am using SQL Server 2012 and I have a database with 1000 tables. My current table design has a single primary key for each table. Now my design has changed to use a composite primary key. How do I add a composite primary key using bulk alter statement?

Eg:

```
alter table table_name 
    add primary key (col_name1, col_name2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `sp_MSforeachtable` system procedure (undocumented) to loop over all tables:

```
EXEC sp_MSforeachtable @command1="alter table ? add primary key (col_name1, col_name2)"
GO
```

Make sure you don't have primary keys defined so that this can run smoothly. It may take some time!

Comment: He has explicitly mentioned that tables have already PRIMARY KEYs defined on single column. This script generates error indicating already existing PK.

Comment: There should be some way to check existing PRIMARY KEYs by using  ``` IF EXISTS ``` or something like this.

Comment: There is a way to do this, but the OP in question asked for a way to add primary key, not to drop existing one.

Comment: Oh I really did. Though, OP seems to be familiar with the fact that he needs to be able to drop the PK in the first place, since he/she attached an example, which may imply that OP already tried this for a single table. Anyways, I will include that in the answer laters.